# How to return a response and then continue working on the request in the background With web API,

Tags: c#-4.0, async-await

I have a web API controller that uses a class library to perform some work.
In that library, I want to start a process that takes long time and return something to the API for it to respond to the user before the process finishes.

I thought using tasks will do it, but my code does not send the response until the task is done.
I do not need to be notified in the code that the task is done.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for either `SignalR`.

Comment: C# 4.0 does not have async-await capabilities.